# There is no error in my code, but the output that should be displaying is not being displayed

Tags: c#

I am not really sure why but when I put break points in and stepped through my code each of the properties return either a null or 0 when they should be the values I put in the main where I mad the instances of the class.

This is my main

```
namespace DemoJobs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string desc;
            decimal rate, time, total;

            Job job1 = new Job("Pour Driveway", 8m, 50.00m);
            Job job2 = new Job("Instal New Windows", 18m, 120m);
            Job job3 = job1 + job2;

            Console.WriteLine("The {0} job will take {1} hours, costing {2} per hour with a total of {3}", 
                job1.Description, job1.Time, job1.Rate.ToString("C"), job1.Total.ToString("C"));

            Console.WriteLine("The {0} job will take {1} hours, costing {2} per hour with a total of {3}", 
                job2.Description, job2.Time, job2.Rate.ToString("C"),  job2.Total.ToString("C"));

            Console.WriteLine("The {0} job will take {1} hours, costing {2} per hour with a total of {3}", 
                job3.Description, job3.Time, job3.Rate.ToString("C"), job3.Total.ToString("C"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my class

```
namespace DemoJobs
{
    public class Job
    {
        // variables
        private string _description;
        private decimal _time, _rate, _total;

        // property for the job description
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; }
        }

        // property for the total job time
        public decimal Time
        {
            get { return _time; }
            set { _time = value; CalcTotal(); }
        }

        // property for the jobs hourly rate
        public decimal Rate
        {
            get { return _rate; }
            set { _rate = value; CalcTotal(); }
        }

        // read-only property for the job total
        public decimal Total
        {
            get { return _total; }
        }

        // method to calculate the total for the job
        public decimal CalcTotal()
        {
            _total = _rate * _time;
            return _total;
        }

        // constructor
        public Job(string description, decimal time, decimal rate)
        {
            Description = _description;

            Time = _time;

            Rate = _rate;
        }

        public static Job operator +(Job job1, Job job2)
        {
            string newDescription = job1.Description + " and " + job2.Description;

            decimal newTime = job1.Time + job2.Time;

            decimal newRate = (job1.Rate + job2.Rate) / 2;

            decimal newTotalFee = newRate * newTime;

            return (new Job(newDescription, newTime, newRate));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm no error? If you have two jobs with different times and rates, then the rate of the combined job is not just the average of the rates of the two jobs.

Comment: There is two parts to the problem, the second part involves making a weighted average for the jobs to make the total fee more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you are using wrong variable references:

```
   public Job(string description, decimal time, decimal rate)
    {
        Description = description;

        Time = time;

        Rate = rate;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply change (an example)

```
Description = _description;

Time = _time;

Rate = _rate;
```

to

```
Description = description;

Time = time;

Rate = rate;
```

In your current code you use instance fields, instead of actual ctor parameters.
Revise your ctor overloads paying attention on this aspect and you done.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your CTOR.
You are assigning the wrong values. Instead of:
 public Job(string description, decimal time, decimal rate)
        {
            Description = _description;

```
        Time = _time;

        Rate = _rate;
    }
```

You should write:
 public Job(string description, decimal time, decimal rate)
        {
            Description = description;

```
        Time = time;

        Rate = rate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Job` constructor has a bug: you are using `description` as parameter, but you assign `_description`.... That one is not provided and is `null`, so your `Description` is also `null`.

Also you could simplify your class a bit by using auto properties

```
public String Description {get; set;}
```

Comment: I changed each of the parts in my constructor and the program displays what it's supposed to, now I have to adjust the formatting and I will be all set. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Job(string description, decimal time, decimal rate)
 {
        Description = _description;

        Time = _time;

        Rate = _rate;
 }
```

You're passing in description not _description...  _description is the private member.

Answer (score 0):

looks maybe like your constructor is backwards...

```
    public Job(string description, decimal time, decimal rate)
    {
        Description = _description;

        Time = _time;

        Rate = _rate;
    }
```

should be
        public Job(string description, decimal time, decimal rate)
        {
            _description = description;

```
        _time = time;

        _rate = rate;
    }
```